# decrementing after array mapping not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a function "Next "that maps an array like in the example below and after incrementing the element I am doing something, but I also have another function "Prev" it pretty much does a similar mapping but in that function, I am decrementing the element. The Next function works fine but the Prev function doesn't, can someone please help me with this?

I am mapping an array of object

```
[
   {
      "id":"v82b3a65",
      "name":"Name"
   },
   {
      "id":"u0b26551",
      "name":"Name2"
   }
]
```

my functions :

```
const Next = () => {
  array.items.map((item, key, element) => {
    var next = element[key ++];
    setId(next.id);
  });
};

const Prev = () => {
  array.items.map((item, key, element) => {
    var prev = element[key --];
    setId(prev.id);
  });
};

render(
<View>
<Button title={'Prev'} onPress={Prev}/>
<Button title={'Next'} onPress={Next}/>
</View>
)
```

I am using those functions in onPress of buttons

The result I need: on Next button press I want it to set setID = next objects id and on Prev button press I want to set setID = previous object id

Comment: Where are you incrementing the element? `index++` increments the index, not the element. Do you mean `var next = value + 1`? Or just `value++` and drop the whole `next` variable, since `++` increments (and updates) the `value` variable.

Comment: please add a bit more code and explain what is happening and what you would like to see happen differently

Comment: @akaphenom I have updated the code

Comment: I am trying to figure out why you are mapping over the array?  I am still not crtain what your desired outcome is?  Map works over each contained instance...

Answer (score 1):

You should check `index` value if it is larger than 0 in `Prev` function. Also check if it is smaller than array length - 1 in `Next` function.

```js
const Next = () => {
  var newArray = myArray.map(function (value, index, elements) {
    if (index < myArray.length - 1) {
      var next = elements[index + 1];
      // do something
    }
  });
};

const Prev = () => {
  var newArray = myArray.map(function (value, index, elements) {
    if (index > 0) {
      var next = elements[index - 1];
      // do something
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: With `++` or `--` after the variable name, the return value is the previous value, and with those before the variable name, the return value is the new value. I think you need to switch the position of the `++` and `--`. Well either switch the position, or just ya know, `+1` or `-1` since you don't need to modify the `index` variable.

Comment: I would suggest using a guard clause if the whole function body is going to be wrapped inside the if-statement. eg. `if (index >= myArray.length - 1) return;` This improves code indention. However I'm not sure what the plan is for when `next` is unavailable. Returning without value would map the element to `undefined`.